# add parmanently code to remote site

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, facebook

As I am using facebook (for example) I'd love to create my own custom extensions to make chat black, or change text color (mostly css and js changes). Is it possible to make my chrome, or firefox do it for me? To replace files or execute code from my additional js files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/).  It does exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) for CSS overrides and [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) to run javascript on events (most commonly when you load a webpage).

Of course, GreaseMonkey CAN be used to override CSS but it's better and more manageable to keep them separated.